# Register additional persistence unit in Keycloak Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, keycloak, quarkus

We have a custom keyloak user storage provide to use our proprietary user database for authentication.

This works perfectly fine with the WildFly based Keycloak. Since Keycloak will drop WildFly support in june 2022 according to their release notes, I am currently trying to get it running in the new, Quarkus based Keycloak distribution.

First I had to remove all dependencies provided by Quarkus since those lead to class loader issues. But now I am stuck with this error when I try to start Keycloak with the command  `./kc.sh start-dev  --log-level=ERROR`:

```
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
ERROR: Unexpected error when starting the server in (development) mode
ERROR: Failed to start quarkus
ERROR: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
ERROR: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

And 'hibernate.dialect' is set in persistence.xml and configuring a persistance unit in persistence.xml should be supported according to quarkus documentation :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="example-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.example.keycloak.provider.db.entity.Benutzer</class>
        <class>com.example.keycloak.provider.db.entity.BenutzerWithSource</class>
        <class>com.example.keycloak.provider.db.entity.Rolle</class>
        <class>com.example.keycloak.provider.db.entity.Parameter</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Configuring the dialect in an application.properties (according to https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multiple-persistence-units) file in the delivery didn't change the behavior as well:
`quarkus.hibernate-orm."example-pu".hibernate-dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional Persistence Units are not supported in Keycloak 17.0.0 with Quarkus.
This should be fixed in Keycloak 18.0.0: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/10581.